# how to get websocket working with play and Concurrent.broadcast

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

Here is what the [document](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWebSockets) recommends and it does work.

```
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.iteratee._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext

def socket =  WebSocket.using[String] { request =>

  // Concurrent.broadcast returns (Enumerator, Concurrent.Channel)
  val (out, channel) = Concurrent.broadcast[String]

  // log the message to stdout and send response back to client
  val in = Iteratee.foreach[String] {
    msg => println(msg)
      // the Enumerator returned by Concurrent.broadcast subscribes to the   channel and will
      // receive the pushed messages
      channel push("I received your message: " + msg)
  }
  (in,out)
}
```

However it is not working if I changed to:

```
def socket =  WebSocket.using[String] { request =>

  val (out, channel) = Concurrent.broadcast[String]

  val in=Iteratee.ignore[String]
  channel push("Hello World")

  (in,out)
}
```

I'd appreciate if you can help me understand why it is not working with the new approach.

Thanks

James

Update:

```
class ServiceHandler extends Actor {

  import Tcp._
  val (enumerator, channel) = Concurrent.broadcast[String]

  val system=ActorDict.system

  def receive = {

    case subscribeData() =>{

      sender !  enumerator


    }

    case Received(data) => {


      val dst = data.decodeString("utf-8")
      val va=dst.substring(dst.lastIndexOf(',') + 1).trim()
        println(va)
           channel.push(va)



    }
    case PeerClosed => context stop self
  }

}




  def ws =  WebSocket.using[String] { request =>

    val in=Iteratee.ignore[String]

    val dataHandler = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[ServiceHandler])

    val out= Await.result((dataHandler ? subscribeData()), 5 seconds).asInstanceOf[Enumerator[String]]


    (in,out)
  }
```

Comment: I assume by "not working" you mean nothing gets pushed back to the client. I'm just guessing, but it could be because you're pushing to the channel before the connection has completed with the client, so they don't receive that particular message.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: yes. it means the client can not receive the "hello world" message.

Comment: I edited my question. so the channel will have data pushed all the time. How come it is still not working since it should have data available after the connection has been established. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will not receive the "hello world" in the client side because you're pushing it to the channel before the connection is established with the client.

If you don't need to receive anything from the client  ( this is why you're doing `val in=Iteratee.ignore[String]` ) You'd better go with server sent events:

```
Ok.chunked(out &> EventSource()).as("text/event-stream")
```

Comment: I edited my question. so the channel will have data pushed all the time. How come it is still not working since it should have data available after the connection has been established. thank you!